# Using append with a Variable in an if Statement Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, syntax, append

I am trying to create a way to add input values to my lists through a user interface that asks you what the category and what word you would like to add it to.

It all works just fine, and as you can see I was trying it out with my test category (the reason for the seemingly unnecessary print statements) **except for one thing: the append statement**.

I want to find a way to put the inputted category in the spot before the append so that the phrase that i want to add will be added to that category.

I am not sure what to put so I tried a number of things: list, (list), userCategory (which is in there now), and (userCategory). I think it is probably a syntax error but it just tells me that those names can't be appended to.

This is the error message:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append

This is my code:

```
testcategory = ['chicken',]
greetingInput = ['hi','HI','Hi','Hello','wazzup','hello','sup','Sup','howdy','Howdy','hey','Hey','What\'s hanging my dude?',]
greetingOutput = ['Hello, how are you?','How\'s it going?','Wazzup','What\'s hanging my dude?',]
greetingResponseP = ['good','great','ok','fine','okay','amazing','splendid','Good','Great','Ok','Fine','Okay','OK','Amazing','Splendid','allright','Allright',]
greetingResponseB = ['bad','sucky','lame','not good','horrible','cruddy','bloody horrible','terrible','Bad','Sucky','Lame','Not good','Horrible','Cruddy','Bloody horrible','Not Good','Bloody Horrible','Terrible']
statusInputandResponseP = ['Good, how are you?','I\'m great, how are you?','i\'m good, how are you?','Good how are you?','I\'m great how are you?','i\'m good how are you?','Im great, how are you?','im good, how are you','Good, how are you','I\'m great, how are you','i\'m good, how are you','Im great, how are you','im good, how are you','Good, hbu?','I\'m great, hbu?','i\'m good, hbu?','Good hbu?','I\'m great hbu?','i\'m good hbu?','Im great, hbu?','im good, hbu','Good, hbu','I\'m great, hbu','i\'m good, hbu','Im great, hbu','im good, hbu','Good how are you?','I\'m great how are you?','i\'m good how are you?','Im great how are you?','im good how are you','Good how are you','I\'m great how are you','i\'m good how are you','Im great how are you','im good how are you','Good hbu?','I\'m great hbu?','i\'m good hbu?','Im great hbu?','im good hbu','Good hbu','I\'m great hbu','i\'m good hbu','Im great hbu','im good hbu',]
statusInput = ['how are you','How are you','how about you','How about you','hbu','HBU','how are you?','How are you?','how about you?','How about you?','hbu?','HBU?','How\'s it going?','how\'s it going?','how\'s it going','How\'s it going','Hows it going?','Hows it going','How\'s it goin\'?','how\'s it goin\'?','how\'s it goin\'','How\'s it goin\'','Hows it goin\'?','Hows it goin\'','How\'s it goin?','how\'s it goin?','how\'s it goin','How\'s it goin','Hows it goin?','Hows it goin',]
userCategory = input("Enter Category: ")
def addInput(list):
        print (testcategory)
        userWord = input("Input the word: ")
        if userCategory == str(list):
                userCategory.append(userWord)
                print (testcategory)

addInput(userCategory)
```

Comment: `userCategory` is a string... you cannot append to a string. I think you want a `dict` with keys that are strings like `'greetingInput'` that have the corresponding `list` objects as values. You then use the `str` object from `input` to recover the correct `list` and then you can append to it

Comment: juanpa.arrivillaga I'm not sure what you meant by your comment can you show me an example of the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this kind of storage you would use a dictionary for the greeting categories, like this:

```
testcategory = 'chicken'
greeting = {}
greeting['greetingInput'] = ['hi','HI','Hi','Hello','wazzup','hello','sup','Sup','howdy','Howdy','hey','Hey','What\'s hanging my dude?',]
greeting['greetingOutput'] = ['Hello, how are you?','How\'s it going?','Wazzup','What\'s hanging my dude?',]
greeting['greetingResponseP'] = ['good','great','ok','fine','okay','amazing','splendid','Good','Great','Ok','Fine','Okay','OK','Amazing','Splendid','allright','Allright',]
greeting['greetingResponseB'] = ['bad','sucky','lame','not good','horrible','cruddy','bloody horrible','terrible','Bad','Sucky','Lame','Not good','Horrible','Cruddy','Bloody horrible','Not Good','Bloody Horrible','Terrible']
greeting['statusInputandResponseP'] = ['Good, how are you?','I\'m great, how are you?','i\'m good, how are you?','Good how are you?','I\'m great how are you?','i\'m good how are you?','Im great, how are you?','im good, how are you','Good, how are you','I\'m great, how are you','i\'m good, how are you','Im great, how are you','im good, how are you','Good, hbu?','I\'m great, hbu?','i\'m good, hbu?','Good hbu?','I\'m great hbu?','i\'m good hbu?','Im great, hbu?','im good, hbu','Good, hbu','I\'m great, hbu','i\'m good, hbu','Im great, hbu','im good, hbu','Good how are you?','I\'m great how are you?','i\'m good how are you?','Im great how are you?','im good how are you','Good how are you','I\'m great how are you','i\'m good how are you','Im great how are you','im good how are you','Good hbu?','I\'m great hbu?','i\'m good hbu?','Im great hbu?','im good hbu','Good hbu','I\'m great hbu','i\'m good hbu','Im great hbu','im good hbu',]
greeting['statusInput'] = ['how are you','How are you','how about you','How about you','hbu','HBU','how are you?','How are you?','how about you?','How about you?','hbu?','HBU?','How\'s it going?','how\'s it going?','how\'s it going','How\'s it going','Hows it going?','Hows it going','How\'s it goin\'?','how\'s it goin\'?','how\'s it goin\'','How\'s it goin\'','Hows it goin\'?','Hows it goin\'','How\'s it goin?','how\'s it goin?','how\'s it goin','How\'s it goin','Hows it goin?','Hows it goin',]

def addInput(category='', word=''):
    print (testcategory)
    if category in greeting:
        greeting[category].append(word)
        print(greeting[category])
        print (testcategory)

userCategory = input("Enter Category: ")
userWord = input("Input the word: ")
addInput(userCategory, userWord)
```

I left the `print` statements from your code, although they don't give any context info.
Check the [Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/index.html) for further information about dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

I think what he means is that you should create a dictionary with the curly brackets that have keys like your categories. Then you can append to that dictionary by calling on that certain key. I think what you need is a tutorial on dictionaries. This platform is used to talk more about errors.

Answer (score 0):

Say suppose you wanted to add item to `greetingInput`
through `input`, if `greetingInput` it is treated as `string` object, not as `list` object for which you intended to add.

To avoid this you can categorize the lists through numbering. Based on that you can use `if..elsif` to add lists. the function code can be modified like below

```
<code>
userWord = input("Input the word: ")
if userCategory == 1:
    greetingInput.append(userWord)
</code>
```